# How to use a Switch statement to select and play a sound fx file

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

I am trying to use a `switch` statement to play a sound file based on the proximity of an iBeacon™. I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

I am developing on Swift 3, Xcode 8.3.2.

```
self.courtMap.showsUserLocation = true

let beacons:[CLBeacon]
let beaconProximity = beacons.first?.proximity

var beaconRanger:AVAudioPlayer = {

    switch beaconProximity {
    case .immediate: return playSound(sound: madeSoundfx)
    case .near: return playSound(sound: madeSoundfx)
    case .far: return playSound(sound: madeSoundfx)
    case . unknown: return playSound(sound: madeSoundfx)

    }        
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Can you show the `playSound` function?

Comment: what is the problem of the code snippet?

Comment: the sound works, but on line 6 "var beaconRanger:AVAudioPlayer" I get an error that says "Cannot convert value of type '() ->' to specified AVPlayer

Answer (score 0):

For a computed property, get rid of the equals sign:

```
var beaconRanger:AVAudioPlayer {
    switch beaconProximity {
    case .immediate: return playSound(sound: madeSoundfx)
    case .near: return playSound(sound: madeSoundfx)
    case .far: return playSound(sound: madeSoundfx)
    case . unknown: return playSound(sound: madeSoundfx)
    }        
}
```

Note that the way you'v written your code your playSound function can't tell which proximity it's being called for. You're going to return the same sound in each case. I would expect you to pass the proximity to the function, or a unique sound name, or something unique based on the different proximity values.